# Corona SDK (LUA) Slide viewer

Tags: image, view, lua, coronasdk, slide

I want to know how I can create a SlideViewer as "SlideView" of SAMPLE CODE but obtain my images from the server.

I try with this, but the image shows always and is not correct.

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 
local slideView = require("slideView")
local myImages = {
        "myPhotos2.jpg",
    "myPhotos3.jpg",
    "myPhotos4.jpg",
        display.loadRemoteImage("http://some huge link.jpg", "GET","", "img_term_435_bmw-mini-logo11.jpg", system.TemporaryDirectory, 0, 0 )
}       
slideView.new( myImages )
```

Answer (score 0):

The SlideView from "CoronaSDK/SampleCode/Interface/SlideView" expects paths for files on the local filesystem. It creates the images in the SlideView with [display.newImage](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html).

You have two options:

1. Change SlideView to use [display.loadRemoteImage](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html) and pass it a table of URLs
2. Pre-download the images to the local filesystem and pass them to SlideView. However you'll still need to modify SlideView's use of `display.newImage` because it's looking for images in `system.ResourceDirectory` instead of `system.TemporaryDirectory`.

Example:

```
network.download("http://example.com/image.jpg", "GET", nil, nil, "img_term_435_bmw-mini-logo11.jpg", system.TemporaryDirectory)

-- Change slideview to load from system.TemporaryDirectory first, then
local slideView = require("slideView")
local myImages = {
    "img_term_435_bmw-mini-logo11.jpg"
}       
slideView.new( myImages )
```